# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{t_{1}x_{1}+t_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+t_{n}x_{n}} { t_{1}+t_{2}+\cdots+t_{n} } \right) = a $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, average

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}=a$  and $\left \{ t_{n} \right\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left ( t_{1}+t_{2}+\cdots+t_{n}\right ) =+\infty $.

Prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 
       \frac{t_{1}x_{1}+t_{2}x_{2}+\cdots+t_{n}x_{n}} { t_{1}+t_{2}+\cdots+t_{n} }  = a 
$$   without using the Toeplitz transformation

I tried to prove it using the Stolz theorem, but I couldn't get it result

Comment: what happened when you use Cesaro-Stolz theorem? It should give you the result right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said, you had a problem with getting the result using Stolz-Cesaro. So, I wrote it down here but I cannot figure out, where you had a problem with it:

- $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n t_k x_k$
- $b_n = \sum_{k=1}^n t_k$
- Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{n+1} = a$

$$\frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_n} = \frac{t_{n+1} x_{n+1}}{t_{n+1}} = x_{n+1} \stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}a$$

Comment: Thanks for showing it, I had already realized where was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The intuition would be, for each particular $n$, you are taking a convex combination
$$
L_n = w_1x_1 + \ldots+w_nx_n, \quad \text{with} \quad w_k = \frac{t_k}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}.
$$

Note that as $n \to \infty$, we have $x_n \to a$ by assumption, so there will be more and more $a$-like terms in $L_n$ and so $a$-like numbers will contribute more and more weight, so the weighted average will shift towards $a$ as expected.

Can you perhaps make this intuitive notion formal?

Comment: Of course, I could do it, thanks a lot for this intuition